# Que un usuario solo pueda modificar su perfil y no otros perfiles a traves del url

Tags: python, mysql, django

Ejemplo: Un usuario accede a `http://127.0.0.1:8000/editperfilusuario/2/` para modificar su perfil, este url contiene el id del usuario, en este caso es 2
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema es que este usuario de id 2, puede modificar informacion de otros usuario cambiando el id en la url.
¿Como puedo hacer para que solo pueda editar su informacion?
**Nota:** El modelo User de Django fue cambiado por Cliente con AbstractUser

La vista que tengo

**view.py:**

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def modificarPerfilUsuario(request, id):
usuario = get_object_or_404(Cliente, id=id)

data = {
    'form': CustomUserCreationFormListado(instance=usuario)
}
if request.method == 'POST':
    formulario = CustomUserCreationFormListado(data=request.POST, instance=usuario)
    if formulario.is_valid():
        formulario.save()
        messages.success(request, "Registro modificado correctamente")
        return redirect(to="/")
    else:
        data["form"] = formulario

return render(request, 'usuarios/modificar.html', data)
```

**url.py:**

```
path('editperfilusuario/<id>/', views.modificarPerfilUsuario, name='editperfilusuario'),
```

**models.py:**

```
class Cliente(AbstractUser):
region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
provincia = models.ForeignKey(Provincia, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
comuna = models.ForeignKey(Comuna, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
test = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**mi tabla usuario en la base de datos es de esta manera:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

intente agregando este codigo

```
`if request.user != usuario.id:
 raise Http404() `
```

pero con cualquier usuario me da error 404 como quise que retornara

**de esta manera quedo agregando el codigo anterior:**

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def modificarPerfilUsuario(request, id):
usuario = get_object_or_404(Cliente, id=id)

if request.user != usuario.id:
   raise Http404() 
 
data = {
    'form': CustomUserCreationFormListado(instance=usuario)
}
if request.method == 'POST':
    formulario = CustomUserCreationFormListado(data=request.POST, instance=usuario)
    if formulario.is_valid():
        formulario.save()
        messages.success(request, "Registro modificado correctamente")
        return redirect(to="/")
    else:
        data["form"] = formulario

return render(request, 'usuarios/modificar.html', data)
```

Comment: Una forma muy muy simple sería poner un `if` comparando el id del usuario que está accediendo al sitio contra el id del perfil del usuario que va a ser modificado, si es el mismo entonces proceder con la edición, de lo contrario bloquear todos los campos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema que tienes es am realizar la comparación entre el objeto que representa el usuario en sesión contra solo el id del usuario.

La comparación para lanzar el error debería ser
`if request.user.id != usuario.id`

Sin embargo, te recomiendo que en lugar de permitir una url que acceda a cualquier usuario y tener que validar, justamente tengas una URL general de edición del usuario que ingresó, y que los datos a mostrar y editar sean por ende de los recuperados de `request.user`. Con esto evitas que por error se pueda editar un usuario diferente o exponer datos.